# Estimating a probability

Tags: probability

For the following question I wanted to know how to estimate the probability that I have selected from bin A.
There are 10 bins, 4 are labelled A, 6 labelled B. Each bin has balls with two colors (Red/ blue). The distribution of red and blue balls in bin A is (0.3 to 0.7) The distribution of red and blue balls in bin B is (0.7 to 0.3). If you randomly draw two balls with replacement and they turn out to be red and blue what is the probability we selected from A?

I am getting (Probability selecting red from any Bin that is A/ Total probability selecting red from all bins)X (Probability selecting blue from any bin that is A/ Total probability of selecting a blue from all bins) =13.7%

Comment: Hi, this question is more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com. When you ask there, please explain in more detail what you have tried and what are the results you are getting; that will make it more likely that someone will want to help with your problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.